# How to set canvas image trasparency

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I've created a small program for generating Minecraft ingot texture with node.js and canvas.
I would like to make the background (everything that is not part of the ingot) transparent.

I've all my rectangles:

```js
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 800
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(0, 200, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 250, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 300, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 350, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 400, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(50, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(100, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(200, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(250, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(300, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(350, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(400, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(450, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(500, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(550, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(600, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(650, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(700, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(150, 550, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(100, 500, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(50, 450, 50, 50);

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

How I can set the image background transparency?

Comment: Just for clarification: what is an ingot texture? Beside that - can you provide some working code or some sketch how your final texture should look like?

Comment: Oh sorry, https://prnt.sc/11458wg this is a screenshot of the ingot.

Comment: In the code you posted there is no image, you just have a bunch of rectangles in a canvas ... can you be a bit more specific

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I've posted the image in the second comment

Comment: @BlackdestinyXX I don't know exactly where your problem is. The Canvas element is transparent by default. In your sample code anything that is not covered by `fillRect()` will be transparent.

Comment: Yes you posted an image in the comments but how is that related to the code? also anything relevant to the question you should edit and add it to the question

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the discussion on the comments:

Your code has no `drawImage` that's what I would expect to see if the issue was with an image.
The canvas is transparent by default, you can see it my sample below I added some  CSS with a background image to the html element, we can see the image is behind the canvas and visible.

```js
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = canvas.height = 800
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.fillRect(0, 200, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 250, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 300, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 350, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(0, 400, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(50, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(100, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(150, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(200, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(250, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(300, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(350, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(400, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(450, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(500, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(550, 0, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(600, 50, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(650, 100, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(700, 150, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(150, 550, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(100, 500, 50, 50);
ctx.fillRect(50, 450, 50, 50);

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```

```css
html {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png');
}
```